# Skip connections for pre-trained model in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

so i am currently implementing the model in the following paper https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2018/papers/Oh_Fast_Video_Object_CVPR_2018_paper.pdf

And as the following model show they used 2 resnet50 inside the model
[Model's Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5htIF.png)
Labeled as the siamese encoders

I used the resnet50 model provided by Keras with following code :

```
input_shape = (480,854,4)
inputlayer_Q = Input(shape=input_shape, name="inputlayer_Q")
convlayer_Q = Conv2D(filters= 3,kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'same')(inputlayer_Q)
model_Q = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(
input_shape=(
  convlayer_Q.shape[1],convlayer_Q.shape[2],convlayer_Q.shape[3]),
  include_top=False,
  weights='imagenet'
 )
```

They then took 3 skip connections from layers inside the resnet model, I tried to takes the skip connections by using the following line

```
res2_skip = model_Q.layers[38].output
res3_skip = model_Q.layers[80].output
res4_skip = model_Q.layers[142].output
```

But when I use it in later in the model and try to run it give me Graph disconnected.

So is there any way to make skip connections/modify models provided by Keras ?

Comment: It's not immediately obvious to me what you're doing wrong. However, I suspect it relates to the way you're using the skip connection layers. So, please provide more of the code and the specific error message (especially the line that the error message points you to).

Comment: @kelkka so the full code here if you want to look at it [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GO0IY2swEvmLzAoCefFzTZUC24_GX42U?usp=sharing) 
but to summarize I am using keras.model (Functional API) to implement the model in the paper.
In the paper's model the used skip connection labeled "res2, res3, res4" to get the output of specific layers in the resnet50 and add it to the output of another layer in the refine modules of the decoder (check the image I linked in the post if lost).
I will continue in another reply.

Comment: @kelkka I am taking the skip connections and then using `Add()` later in the code, the problem is that whenever I am try to run the following line   `main_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputlayer_Q,inputlayer_M],outputs=output,name ="main model" )`.
 I get this error 

"Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 480, 854, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_3'), name='input_3', description="created by layer 'input_3'") at layer "conv1_pad". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add minimal reproducible example, or at least an attempt, i.e. fix the imports,... . See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
input_shape = (480,854,4)


# Target Stream  = Q
inputlayer_Q = Input(shape=input_shape, name="inputlayer_Q")
# Refrence Stream = M
inputlayer_M = Input(shape=input_shape,name="inputlayer_M")


convlayer_Q = Conv2D(filters= 3,kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'same')(inputlayer_Q)
convlayer_M = Conv2D(filters= 3,kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'same')(inputlayer_M)

model_Q = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(
    input_shape=(convlayer_Q.shape[1],convlayer_Q.shape[2],convlayer_Q.shape[3]), include_top=False, weights='imagenet' 
)
model_Q._name ="resnet50_Q"

model_M = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(
    input_shape=(convlayer_M.shape[1],convlayer_M.shape[2],convlayer_M.shape[3]), include_top=False, weights='imagenet' 
)
model_M._name ="resnet50_M"

for model in [model_Q, model_M]:
  for layer in model.layers:
    old_name = layer.name
    layer._name = f"{model.name}_{old_name}"
    print(layer._name)
    

encoder_Q = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model_Q.inputs, outputs=model_Q.output,name ="encoder_Q" )
encoder_M = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model_M.inputs, outputs=model_M.output,name ="encoder_M" )


concatenate = Concatenate(axis=0,name ="Concatenate")([encoder_Q.output, encoder_M.output])
global_layer = GlobalConvBlock(concatenate)

res2_skip = encoder_Q.layers[38].output
res2_skip = ZeroPadding2D(padding=(0,1), data_format=None)(res2_skip)
res3_skip = encoder_Q.layers[80].output
res3_skip = ZeroPadding2D(padding=((0,0),(0,1)), data_format=None)(res3_skip)
res4_skip = encoder_Q.layers[142].output


ref1_16 = refineblock(res4_skip,global_layer,"ref1_16")
ref1_8 = refineblock(res3_skip,ref1_16,"ref1_8")
ref1_4 = refineblock(res2_skip,ref1_8,"ref1_4")
outconv = Conv2D(filters= 2,kernel_size = (3,3)) (ref1_4)
outconv1 = ZeroPadding2D(padding=((1,1),(0,0)), data_format=None)(outconv)
output = Softmax()(outconv1)

main_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[encoder_Q.inputs, encoder_M.inputs],outputs=output, name ="main model" )
```

Comment: First of all thanks a lot , but doesn't this mean that the first two layers "convlayer_Q"  and "convlayer_M" aren't included in my model ?

Comment: I just created new model on top of them and added the conv layers so I am all good, I just want to know if you have time what was the problem.

Comment: Regarding your first question: I don't know, you'd have to print the model summary with model.summary(). The second question is easier to answer: basically, where you set encoder_Q and encoder_M models, you needed to set the inputs to model_Q.inputs and model_M.inputs because tf.keras.applications are basically models (as far as I know). I.E. you needed to do in the middle what you do on the last line where you set main_model. I additionally renamed each layer in the tf.keras.applications models because keras can't separate between layers if their names are the same and fails.